# What do you call the technique in CSS where you select an element based on its ancestors?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project with an example that could be simplified to the following. What do you call the name of the technique being used in the CSS?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        #numberone #numbertwo #numberthree
        {
            color: red;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="numberone">
            <div id="numbertwo">
                <div id="numberthree">
                    This is red
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="numberthree">
            This is not red
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If that's your real code, your markup is invalid. ID values must be unique in a document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the use of [descendant combinators](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) to target an element with a specific ancestor structure. From the spec:

> A descendant combinator is whitespace that separates two sequences of
>   simple selectors. A selector of the form "A B" represents an element B
>   that is an arbitrary descendant of some ancestor element A.

I'm going to modify your CSS to use class selectors rather than ID selectors, since ID values have to be unique in a document. This example will select elements with the class name `numberthree` that are descendants of elements with the class name `numbertwo` that are descendants of elements with the class name `numberone`:

```
.numberone .numbertwo .numberthree {
    color: red;
}
```

Whereas this example will select all elements with the class name `numberthree` regardless of their ancestors:

```
.numberthree {
    color: red;
}
```

So given your example markup (again, modified to use classes) the following would apply:

```
<div class="numberone">
    <div class="numbertwo">
        <div class="numberthree">
            This is red for both snippets above
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="numberthree">
    This is only red for the second snippet above
</div>
```

Comment: Before the descendant combinator got its name, the entire selectors used to be known as [contextual selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#contextual-selectors), where you select an element only in a certain "context". This terminology is notably missing in more recent specs...

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks, I never knew that. Your incredible knowledge of CSS never ceases to amaze me!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback all and the details explanation @JamesAllardice

Comment: @Damien I understand the question was vague but really couldn't think of a better way to write it after doing a bit of research! I am really trying to get a better handle of some of the CSS in the projects I am working on this year (as a PHP dev) and want to understand what I am seeing in the code from a CSS perspective.